# reference binding to null pointer error during vector insertion

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve a particular leetcode problem but I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong.

The question is this one:https://leetcode.com/problems/group-anagrams/
and my code is:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<string>> groupAnagrams(vector<string>& str) {
        unordered_map<string, vector<int>> map;
        vector<string> newstr = str;
        int size = str.size();
        //pushing those indices of `str` into the map which share common permutation
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            sort(newstr[i].begin(), newstr[i].end());
            map[newstr[i]].push_back(i);
        }

        vector<vector<string>> ans;
        int i=0;
        for(auto itr: map){
            int v_size = itr.second.size();
            for(int j=0; j<v_size; j++)
                //cout<<str[itr.second[j]]<<" "; //this query works perfectly
                ans[i].push_back(str[itr.second[j]]); //erroneous code
            i++;
        }
        return vector<vector<string>>();
        // return ans;
    }
};
```

Comment: What makes you think that this code is erroneous? Is your compiler complaining?

Comment: The ans has the fix. However your code can be improved. Especially, you most likely don't need to deal with indexes. Here is my version: https://pastebin.com/raw/uARbVh13

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are accessing `ans[i]` without allocating any memory in `ans` beforehand. This creates a data access that is out of the vector's bounds (0).
If you meant to add a new vector to ans, use `ans.push_back()`. As balki said, you can also remove redundant allocations by allocating all entries upon declaration, like this:

```cpp
vector<vector<string>> ans { map.size() };
```

This will make your code work without any additional changes needed (as far as I can see).

Comment: or initialize ans with size of map, like `vector<vector<string>> ans(map.size())`

Comment: @balki that worked. but a few questions: a) if I initialize the size with 10 and if I add 11 elements, would I face any issues? b) if I initialize the size with 10 and after adding 2 elements, if I fetch the size of the vector would it show 10? or 2?

Comment: @KaranSingh a) depends on how you add them: If you simply use ans[12], then it's illegal, but if you use ans.push_back(), then it allocates a new entry and adds the value at the end.

Comment: @KaranSingh I would seriously recommend reading the [C++ documentation of the vector class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), to learn what each operation does, and what you have to watch out for when using them.

Comment: @KaranSingh I also suggest, for better code clarity, that you convert `vector<vector<string>>` into some meaningfully named class type. This makes the code much easier to understand and reason about.

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
ans[i].push_back(str[itr.second[j]]);
```

`i` needs to be a valid index. Since you have not added any items to `ans` before that call, `ans` is empty and you have an out of bounds index error. Change the line defines `ans` to initialize it with appropriate size.

Instead of

```
vector<vector<string>> ans;
```

use

```
vector<vector<string>> ans(map.size());
```

---

A second option will be to create a `std::vector<std::string>` in the loop and add it to `ans`.

```
for(auto itr: map){
    int v_size = itr.second.size();

    std::vector<std::string> v;
    for(int j=0; j<v_size; j++)
        v.push_back(str[itr.second[j]]);

    ans.push_back(v);
}
```

Comment: in the second option, how are we able to push back a string in `s` and also able to push back a string in `ans` when `ans` is expecting a vector<string> to be pushed into it?

Comment: @KaranSingh, `str[iter.second[j]]` is `char`. That's why you can push it to `s`.

Comment: @KaranSingh, sorry, my bad. I misunderstood. Let me fix the answer.

Comment: @KaranSingh, it's fixed now.